# Windows Registry Permissions

Tags: windows

I have a service that runs as the "Local System" user. I would like to edit an entry in the registry from this service. This entry lives in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Everything goes find except that the entry is not updated. My service seems to have access to a virtual registry. When I execute `regedit` from this service I access a registry different from the "real" one (the one I access by executing `regedit` from the desktop for instance).
How can I access the "real" registry from my service?

Comment: [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!